# Angular 5 Looping through array of objects

Tags: angular

I Have a server response, consisting of an object and array of objects like below:

```
{
    "bookNumber": "123214",
    "Desc": "book desc",
    "title": "title here",
    "published": "12/01/2016",
    "author": {
        "authorname": "VictorA"
    },

    "Category": [{
        "genere": "Type1",
        "number": "2331",
        "sesction": "Fiction"
    }, {
        "genere": "type2",
        "number": "430359",
        "sesction": "Kids"
    }, {
        "genere": "type2",
        "number": "436430",
        "sesction": "Kids"
    }, {
        "genere": "type2",
        "number": "123914",
        "sesction": "Kids"
    }],

    "Publisher": [{
        "name": "Pubbook",
        "pubId": "81.25402-0233",
        "lastModified": "2012-02-09"
    }]
}
```

On the component i subscribe to the Observable from the service like below:

```
this.myService.getDetails(id).subscribe (data => {  
      this.resp = data;
      console.log (JSON.stringify(this.resp));
    })
```

in the HTML:

I'm using *ngFor to loop through response like below:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" 
           href="#collapseOne">
          Book
        </a>
      </h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
            {{bookNumber}}
            ...so on
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel2">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" 
           href="#collapseTwo" class="collapsed">
          Documents
        </a>
      </h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body" *ngFor = "let item of resp.Category"></div>
            // here How can I  extract items based on genere type e.g. Type1 <div col="md-6"> {{items of Type1 genere}} {{}}</div>
            //  Type2 <div col="md-6">{{items of Type2 genere}}</div>

            I want to display details of each Genere in separately and update on selection for e.g. when i click Number 2331 get details of that object, and same for 4302359
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

How to loop over Category array based on Genere Type(1,2...etc) and update details of each item once user click on number?

Comment: Try to transform the data coming from your server to a data structure that suits you.

Comment: @AnisTissaoui, can you provide an example? :)

Comment: Edit the post and provide more explanations. I don't get why you subscribe and get data and then you assign it to this.resp but then you log this.items that i know nothing about.

Comment: Thank you, I edited console.log it was wrong...I subscribe to observable then assign it to this.resp to iterate over the object

Comment: Is the object you provided is the complete response of the server ? or a part of it ?

Comment: This may not qualify as an answer but if you have a list of books with different genres you can filter them like this: books.filter(book => book.category.genre === 'YourType'). But you should use that in the .ts file.

Comment: The complete response has 2 more arrays like Publisher

Comment: And the resp.Documents ? i can't find the documents object.
Please consider re-writing your question. It should be completely understandable.

Comment: @Anis Tissaoui , Thank you again that was a wrong object indeed I edited it, should be Category obviously, as for your answer how do I use the filtered type on HTML?

Comment: If you know the types you can create different arrays for each type using the filter method i mentioned in your component.ts file. And use ngFor on these arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to leverage *ngIf directive to render specific template and then to pass item data via your method on click/tap:

```html
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body" *ngFor="let item of resp.Category" (click)="itemTapped(item)">
      <div *ngIf="item.type ==='Type1'"></div>
      <div *ngIf="item.type ==='Type2'"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please also make sure you adopt certain coding conventions about var names etc. Your code shared is full of typos and white spaces etc which is really risky;)

Addition: if you want to only show certain categories it really depends on whether you want a user to be able to filter data or if it is up to your app.

If it is just the app just render what you want using *ngIf condition.

```html
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body" *ngFor="let item of resp.Category" (click)="itemTapped(item)">
      <div *ngIf="item.type ==='Type1'"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if it us user controlled - describe your specific User Experience.
I would recommend this article: https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/

Comment: Thank you, that suggestion is after I apply .filter to the response as suggested above by Anis?

Comment: you can skip doing filter actually as *ngIf will create or skip a delegate template. Let me add this to the answer as example

Comment: Thank a lot for the update and advice :) and how do you suggest to render the details (genere, number, section) for each item of genere type?

Comment: can you share a screenshot of how you envision the UI to look like? based on your code it is hard to get it

Comment: so the top part of the screenshot - is that just 2 separate lists what is that UI really? what if lists are 10+ items? Nico if you need help further you seriously need to update your question with the desired outcome you are trying to get to. This screen shot you shared doesn't provide full clarity.

Comment: I will consider it, thank you, there won't be +10 items the sketch provided covers all the cases, upvoting your ngIf works as intended :)

Comment: I see, cool. I normally follow the approach to "mock" up my template first (instead of ngFor use some data to actually populate the screen with proper UI elements) and then start thinking how to do that using data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using GroupBy.

GroupBy pipe returns an object of a key/value pair. https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes#groupby

You need to install the ngx-pipes first, installation process: https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes#installation

Below is the sample piece of code that works perfectly for your data structure:

```
 <div class="panel-body" *ngFor="let item; of resp.Category | groupBy: 'genere' | pairs">
   <h2> {{item[0]}}</h2>
   <div col="md-6" *ngFor="let i of item[1]">
     {{i.number}}, {{i.sesction}}
   </div>
 </div>
```

For reference you can check a similar thing here:
https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes/issues/33#issuecomment-284863058